# how to know if a row has a foreign key on other table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, foreign-key-relationship

hi guys i've been searching and trying with no luck for a solution regarding my two tables in an ms sql 2008 r2 my tables are below:

```
table 1
pk personid varchar - i manually insert here from GUID
fname varchar
mname varchar
lname varchar
qualifier varchar

table 2
pk id - increment by 1
fk personid varchar
salary int
deductions int
salary_month int
salary_year int
```

now my aim here is to know which entries have a foreign key on the other table if not i want to delete it

i really need some help i have been trying it for a couple of weeks

Comment: Do you want to know which rows in table 1 do not have a corresponding entry in table 2?   Not sure what you are asking for.  Can you show your attempts so far?

Comment: Why are you storing GUIDs in a `varchar` column instead of `uniqueidentifier`? Why is your pk for table 1 a GUID and your pk in table 2 an INT IDENTITY?

Comment: because on table 2 it accepts multiple entries that is why i have an int identifier increment by 1

Comment: @sparky ah i am trying to query those entries in table 1 that do not have a relationship in table or do not have entry in table

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand sorry for the mistake yeah i did store it on a uniqueidentifier i stand corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, you want this?

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.personid=t1.personid)
```

Comment: what will this query return?

Comment: This query returns all rows from table_1 which doesn't corresponding PersonId in table_2.

Comment: thanks i will try your answer. be right back with the result.thanks

Answer (score -1):

Here is a query that will give you a list of all foreign keys that exist in your database.

```
select FK.name as [Foreign_Key_Name], T.name as [Referenced_Table], T2.name as [Parent_Table]
from sys.foreign_key_columns FKC
inner join sys.tables T on FKC.referenced_object_id = T.object_id
inner join sys.tables T2 on FKC.parent_object_id = T2.object_id
inner join sys.foreign_keys FK on FKC.constraint_object_id = FK.object_id
```

If you have some columns that are used like foreign keys but there is no actual FK object inside your database then you can try something like this

```
select *
from table1 T1
inner join table2 T2 on T1.ColumnX = T2.ColumnY
```

If query returns a lot of rows than those two columns are probably in a FK relationship.